# Removing slowmode with slowmode command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Alright so I have a slowmode command for my discord bot, setting the slowmode works fine, but I have made it so if there is no argument it will just set slowmode to 0 (no slowmode), that is the only part that is not working.

Code for removing the slowmode:

```js
 if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser('0');
            message.channel.send('Slowmode has been turned off for this channel')
        }
```

This is the full code to the command:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms')

module.exports = {
    name: 'slowmode',
    aliases: ['sm'],
    description: "sets a slowmode for a channel",
    execute(Client, message, args){
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) return message.reply("[ERROR] Invalid permissions. Permissions missing: BAN_MEMBERS. If you think this is a mistake, please contact support.")

        if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser('0');
            message.channel.send('Slowmode has been turned off for this channel')
        }


       const rawTime = args[0]
       const time = ms(rawTime)

       if (isNaN(time)) return message.channel.send("[ERROR] The time you provided is not a number.")
       if (time < 1000) return message.channel.send("[ERROR] You cannot put the slowmode under 1 second.") 
       if (time > 21600) return message.channel.send("[ERROR] You cannot put the slowmode over 6 hours. ")


       message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(time / 1000);
       message.channel.send(`Slowmode has been set to ${args[0]} for this channel.`)

       



    }
}
```

This is the error that I get when I run the command with no argument:

```
Error: val is not a non-empty string or a valid number. val=undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Venom\node_modules\ms\index.js:34:9)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Venom\commands\slowmode.js:18:28)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Venom\events\guild\message.js:10:25)
```

Comment: The error comes from your `message.js` file, that I guess handles the `message` event.

Comment: I do not think it is.

Comment: Here is the code for the message.js: https://sourceb.in/2uSGwor9ou

Comment: Oh, I see now... You forgot to return when `args[0]` is `undefined`. The error comes from a library, when you supply a wrong value to `ms()`.

Comment: I wrote an answer to the question below. Consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return from the function when `args[0]` is `undefined`. The error comes from a library, when you supply a wrong value to the `ms()` function.

Also it would make more sense to pass a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead of [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) to the `.setRateLimitPerUser()` method. As said in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setRateLimitPerUser).

```js
if (!args[0]) {
    message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(0);
    message.channel.send('Slowmode has been turned off for this channel');
    return;
}
```